# I want to read in a file from the command line in python

Tags: python, command

How do I read in a file from python at the command line? So let's say i have a `text.txt` file and I want to do `$ python prefixer.py text.txt`, how would I read in the text file in my `prefixer.py`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1],"r")
contents = f.read()
f.close()
print contents
```

or, better,

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
print contents
```

Comment: I don't see this open command in the sys package.  Can anyone point me to the docs on this?

*Edit* : Just found _http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open_

Answer (score 10):

I think `fileinput` is a lot nicer for this. Easy to use for simple scripts:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

Then you can do `python myscript.py file.txt` or even pipe it in. Purrfect!

https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

file_name = sys.argv[1]
f = open(file_name)
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

Comment: Don't forget to import `argv` from `sys`

Comment: If you have more arguments, you should use OptParse to read arguments.

Comment: Or the improved `argparse` on Python 3.2+